# Why are my custom process.env not working within dotenv?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, local, dotenv

Learning that it is a bad practice to include API secret keys I've done some research and trying to learn how to create custom `process.env`.

After reading:

- [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786)
- [How to set NODE_ENV to production/development in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x)
- [How to set process.env from the file in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385158/how-to-set-process-env-from-the-file-in-nodejs)
- [dotenv file is not loading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335016/dotenv-file-is-not-loading-environment-variables)

I'm trying to set an env file locally based on `process.env.NODE_ENV`. The application would be hosted on Heroku and in my .gitignore I have `dev.env`  but when I try to use [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) locally I'm getting an `undefined`. I have set the environment locally with `export NODE_ENV=development` in my terminal. When I run the command `npm start` or `nodemon` both return `undefined` but in *env.js* I get `Testing for: development`, example:

```
nodemon

[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Testing for: development
undefined
```

Here is what I have:

*app.js*:

```
const keys = require('./config/env')
return console.log(process.env.PORT)
```

*config/env.js*:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
console.log(`Testing for: ${env}`)
try {
  switch(env) {
    case 'undefined':
      Error('Environment undefined, if local in terminal: export NODE_ENV=development')
      break
    case 'development':
      require('dotenv').config({
        path: './dev.env'
      })
      break
    case 'production':
      require('dotenv').config({
        path: './prod.env'
      })
      break
    default:
      Error('Unrecognized Environment')
  }  
} catch (err) {
  Error('Error trying to run file')
}
```

*config/dev.env*:

```
## Port number to run Application
PORT=4321
```

but in *app.js* when I test with `return console.log(process.env.PORT)` or `return console.log(keys.PORT)` they both log `undefined`, why? I seem to be doing something wrong in *env.js* when using `dotenv`.

To clarify I'm not even pushing to Heroku yet and *prod.env* will be validation. If there is a better approach please educate me.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running node server with "NODE_ENV=development node src/main.js"

Comment: I’m running nodemon and in app.js calling the console.log. When calling env.js and logging NODE_ENV I’m getting a log of ‘development’

Comment: I think you should run script like this: **NODE_ENV=development nodemon main.js**

Comment: @d337 my understanding is if `export NODE_ENV=development` was set than it should work with `npm start` or `nodemon`

Comment: Also, when in *app.js* doing a `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` returns **development** in the terminal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've figured where I was going wrong after re-reading the documentation regarding [`path`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path), example:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' })
```

After changing:

```
case 'development':
  require('dotenv').config({
    path: './dev.env'
  })
  break
```

to:

```
case 'development':
  require('dotenv').config({
    path: `${__dirname}/dev.env`
  })
  break
```

it works. So my error was a scope issue. No need to set `const keys` so just using `require('./config/env')` I can access any custom processes, example:

```
process.env.CUSTOM
```

or in this case it would be:

```
process.env.PORT
```

from *app.js*

Comment: For future reference, dotenv will return an error if it can't find or read the file you specify with the `path` option. We surface errors to help with debugging like this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi at first use `switch(env.trim())`, then change the path value `path: './config/dev.env'`. Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku doesn't run on dotenv.

It has something called "Config Vars" within the Settings page of the given Heroku App:

For example

[image: Heroku Config Vars]

For your example, if the code wants to access: `process.env.NODE_ENV`, you would set a new Config Var within your Heroku Settings page of the given app, and call it `NODE_ENV`. Set the value you want, and press save. Voila. Done.

The added value of dotenv is usually for testing on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you need to set those environment variables, as we don't have .env files there whereas on dev server dotenv set it for you using your .env file.

You need to set those variables either via the web interface or the heroku CLI.
[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) heroku doc will help you.

Comment: I know how to set in the CLI the issue is using the custom process in development. Think you’re misunderstanding the question. I can log the NODE_ENV so the error is from env.js to dotenv.

Comment: as I have looked, `config()` takes path to directory where file named **.env** is located. So that's one problem. What we do is replace .env with the file .env.<build_type> before build.

Comment: And that is why in *env.js* I'm setting the path in `config` with `path: './dev.env'`. I may be doing this wrong but per the documentation that is the correct way to declare a file if not using `.env`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are seeing the variables using `echo $var` but `process.env.var` is giving you undefined, then make sure you have that `export` keyword when creating the variable.
`export var="value"`