# Node.js environmental variables ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to read environmental variables in ES6.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config()
```

I did the following however when I attempt to use

```
process.env.example
```

Like I've always done in common JS I get an error message stating that process is not defined. Can someone help me ?

Comment: `process` is a node.js global. using ES6 or anything other syntax should not change it. How are you running it?

Comment: Might be helpful but when I was starting to use `dotenv` I ran into an issue so I asked this question: "[Why are my custom process.env not working within dotenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213162/why-are-my-custom-process-env-not-working-within-dotenv)"

Answer (score 0):

in it's written in their docs

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' 
dotenv.config()
```

Here is an explanation ; you can read more here =>  https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

> When you run a module containing an import declaration, the modules it
> imports are loaded first, then each module body is executed in a
> depth-first traversal of the dependency graph, avoiding cycles by
> skipping anything already executed.
>
> – [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)

**What does this mean in plain language? It means you would think the following would work but it won't.**

```
// errorReporter.mjs
import { Client } from 'best-error-reporting-service'

export default new Client(process.env.API_KEY)

// index.mjs
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

import errorReporter from './errorReporter.mjs'
errorReporter.report(new Error('documented example'))
```

> process.env.API_KEY will be blank.
>
> Instead the above code should be written as..

```
// errorReporter.mjs
import { Client } from 'best-error-reporting-service'

export default new Client(process.env.API_KEY)

// index.mjs
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

import errorReporter from './errorReporter.mjs'
errorReporter.report(new Error('documented example'))
```

Answer (score -1):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` is the message you get when running `process.env.example` in the browser console. You will only be able to access this environment variable on the server side, and not the client side.

Comment: I said that im using Node.js tho ...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
```

As indicated by that library docs in case you are using ES6 instead of the old `require()` method.

See also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv